# How to set priorities for RQ queues under different supervisor programs

Tags: django, redis, supervisord, django-rq, rq

I'm using supervisor to run rqworker. I want to assign different number of workers for different queues, so I put each queue under a different program. How do I set priorities for these queues in this case? I know if I run workers for all the queues under single program, the order I specify queues in rqworker command is the priority of these queues. (https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/#strategies-for-dequeuing-jobs-from-queues) However, for my case, each queue is under a different program, wondering how I can set the priority. Should I start rqworker with nice command? Some config example would be nice. Thx!